# Can we add HTML5/Jscript to ASP.Net MVC2 Project

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-ajax

I wonder to know if we can add HTML5/Jscript files  to ASP.Net MVC2 Project?
If yes , How ?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC is a pattern where you have total control over the views. This means that you can write any javascript and HTML markup you like. If you like HTML5, then you can use HTML5.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , but I wonder to know how , any example can you recommend .

Comment: @TZano asks, how what? You want to use HTML5 in an ASP.NET MVC 2 application? Simply go to the Site.Master file that was generated by the visual studio wizard when you create a new application and modify the DOCTYPE to HTML5. If you want to learn more about HTML5 don't hesitate to checkout http://diveintohtml5.org/